# Guaranteeing field values to be a contiguous sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
mysql> describe obj;
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| data     | blob     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sequence | int(11)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| created  | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want the values in field `sequence` to be a contiguous sequence, i.e. without skipping and hopping, and based on `created` timestamp. Currently I obtain this at application level. After each insert:

```
while (true)
   lastSequence = max(sequence)
   if (update obj with lastSequence + 1)
      break
```

This way it can't skip, but there is no guarantee that the `sequence` order is the same as the `created` one. On the other hand, I could order by `created` in a subquery, but in a cuncurrent environment weird things could happen while the subquery executes if I don't serialize all writes, but I think this would kill performances. Any idea on this subject?

Comment: The values for `id` will b a contiguous sequence. Why do you also need the `sequence` field?

Comment: Will you delete from this table?

Comment: This is not true. For example if a transaction rollbacks usually the auto_inc field is not restored

Comment: @biziclop no, nothing can be deleted from this table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic bullet.

Autoincrementing id numbers won't work, because you'll get a gap if a transaction rolls back.

Application code outside a transaction won't work, because it can't guarantee that the order of "sequence" will match the order of "created".

Doing all the work within a single, serializable transaction will work, but will definitely affect performance. Whether it affects performance so much it's unusable is an open question; test and measure.

So something like this (PostgreSQL) should work, but might not be fast enough. (Take the timings below with a grain of salt. No concurrent users, small tables.)

```
set transaction isolation level serializable;
begin;

insert into obj (sequence, time_created)
select min(n), current_timestamp 
from serial_integers where time_stamp is null;
-- 0.125ms

update serial_integers
set time_stamp = current_timestamp
where n = (select min(n)
from serial_integers where time_stamp is null);
-- 0.161ms

commit;
-- 15ms
```

In practice, I'd test wrapping this in a function (stored procedure), in part to eliminate the subquery in the UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you use auto_increment just like you are using in the ID field.

In oracle you would use a sequencer.

This problem has been around for ages.  The problem is that you would have to lock things when you are determining MAX(value) since you cannot be sure that another process has not inserted another record.

Gaps **will** happen if you delete records.  If you want to use date/time values you have to come down to the sub millisecond level since databases are very fast.  Oracle uses systimestamp and it carries the seconds out to 6 places at least.

Comment: That's why there is a sequence field :)
I will never delete from this table. Once a record is inserted it will stay forever. So your suggestion is to lock things, but how will this impact performance?

Comment: No my suggestion is to most assuredly NOT to lock things.  Use auto_increment on MySQL or a sequencer on Oracle.  You can't set a sequencer on dates and times that is not how they work.  If you want to use dates and time then set the default value for the column to an appropriate type for your database and that way the stamp will be as of record insertion although there is still the remote possibility of tie do to threading and caching.

Comment: @FlyingGuy: One of the OP's requirements is "no gaps". Autoincrementing integers on every platform may have gaps if a transaction rolls back.

Comment: Well then the only way to absolutely guarantee this is to lock the entire table which will throw performance into the toilet.  This also has the possibility of hanging the table.  If your process goes to hell, the lock will stay there until it unwinds itself.